# I am able to review suggested edits before 1500

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, privileges

The rep quotas for betas are lower than on graduated sites. On those, it normally takes about 3K to review suggested edits and tag wiki edits. Here, it is [supposed to take 1.5K](https://music.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits). However, I'm not yet quite there (7 points away). However, I have already made [9 suggested edit reviews](https://music.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats).

Is this a typo on the privileges page or a bug? My guess is that it is somehow related to the new review beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On all Stack Exchange sites, reviewing suggested edits to **tag wikis** and **tag wiki excerpts** requires more reputation than reviewing edits to other post types.

On Music in particular, reviewing edits to questions or answers requires [1000 rep](https://music.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), while reviewing edits to tag wikis and tag wiki excerpts requires [1500 rep](https://music.stackexchange.com/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

Comment: Why doesn't the privileges page indicate that? It seems, from looking at it, it takes 1.5K to do both.

Comment: Hmm. Is this universal for all beta sites?

Comment: We'll clean up the language on the privilege pages. Thanks.